# Testing future Callouts

Tags: code-coverage, callout, failing-tests, future, httpcalloutmock

I am trying to make a future callout sending email name etc from a trigger when a lead is created which is working. The problem is Testing. I am not sure how to go about making this work. I have been reading for days and can't seem to make the past 10 years of other people having this issue fit my needs.

Here is the Trigger:

```
trigger SendGridLeadCreation on Lead (after insert) {
   static List<Map<String, Object>> jsonMAP = new List<Map<String, Object>>();

//TriggerLogic
List<String> lead_ids = new List<String>();
for(Lead lead : Trigger.new) {
lead_ids.add(lead.Id);
 string leadid = lead.Id;
 string ecname = lead.Agency_Type__c;
  string email = lead.Email;
  string fname = lead.FirstName;
  string lname = lead.LastName;
  string marea = lead.Market_Area__c;

  email_campaign__c EeC = new Email_Campaign__c(email__c = email, first_name__c  = fname, last_name__c = lname, name=ecname + ' Campaign', lead__c=leadid, agency_type__c =ecname, Market_Area__c =marea, campaign_type__c='engagement');
            insert eec;
  email_campaign__c MC = new Email_Campaign__c(email__c = email, first_name__c  = fname, last_name__c = lname, name='Marketing Campaign', lead__c=leadid, agency_type__c =ecname, Market_Area__c =marea, campaign_type__c='marketing');
            insert mc;
   string ecid = eec.id;

 for (email_campaign__c ec : [
                SELECT Email__c, First_Name__c, Last_Name__c , Campaign_Age__c, 
            Agency_Type__c, Market_area__c
                FROM email_campaign__c
                WHERE id  = :ecid]) {
                    Map<String, Object> mapped = new Map<String, Object>{ 
                        'market' => ec.Market_Area__c,   //they are flipped at serailization 
                        'type' => ec.Agency_Type__c,     //to come out correct listed in reverse                 
                        'age' => ec.Campaign_Age__c,
                        'last_name' => ec.Last_Name__c,
                        'first_name' => ec.First_Name__c,
                        'email' => ec.Email__c
                            }; jsonMAP.add(mapped); system.debug(mapped);}


                 String jsonString = JSON.serialize(jsonMAP);  
                //send the jsonpayload, endpoint uri, and verb
                SendGridAPI.sendRequest(jsonString,'/v3/contactdb/recipients', 'POST'); system.debug(jsonString);                
  }
}
```

Here is the Code to be Tested:

```
public class SendGridAPI {

// This is the URL of your forwarding server
public static String endpointBase = 'https://api.sendgrid.com';
//Get the api key stored in encrpted text field
public static  String apikey = [select api__c from Key__c where name = 'a001I000001NO0c'].api__c;
// testing strings
public static string testbody = null; 
public static string testpoint = null;
public static integer scode = 0;

@future(callout=true)
public static void sendRequest(String json_payload, String endpoint, String httpMethod) {    

  system.debug(json_payload);

  //Instantiate an httpRequest and set the required attributes
  httpRequest req = new httpRequest();

      //if httpMethod is patch
    if(httpMethod == 'PATCH'){
        req.setMethod('POST');
        endpoint += '?_HttpMethod=PATCH';
    }else{
        req.setMethod(httpMethod);
    }

  req.setEndpoint(endpointBase + endpoint);
  system.debug(endpointBase + endpoint);

  // format headers 
  req.setHeader('Authorization', 'BEARER ' + apikey);
  req.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');

  // set json body from 
  req.setBody(json_payload);

  // prepart to send request
  httpresponse res = new httpresponse();
  Http h = new Http();

        // check if test is running
      if (!Test.isRunningTest()) {
      res = h.send(req);
      system.debug(res);
      }         //do this if test running
          Else{
              testbody = '{"Status":" Created"}';
              testpoint = endpointBase +  endpoint;
              scode = 201;
  }


}
}
```

Here are the Tests I have tried so far:

```
@isTest
private class SendGridAPI_Callout_Test {


@isTest static void testCallout() {

insert new Key__c(api__c = 'foobar', name = 'a001I000001NO0c');

//test strings
string jsonString = '{"email":"test@test.test","first_name":"test"}';
string endpoint = '/v3/contactdb/recipients';
string method = 'POST';
Lead lead = new Lead(lastname='test', company='test', email='test@test.test' );
insert lead;
//Start Test
test.startTest();

// Set mock callout class 
Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new Mock_SendGrid_Response());
    //sendrequest strings
    SendGridapi.sendRequest(jsonString, endpoint, method);
    // trigger schedulabes
    SGsegUPDT segup = new SGsegUPDT(); 
    segup.execute(null);
test.stopTest();

// Verify response received contains fake values
String actualValue = SendGridAPI.testbody;
system.debug(actualvalue);
String expectedValue = '{"Status":"Created"}';
system.debug(expectedValue);
System.assertEquals(actualValue, expectedValue);
System.assertEquals(201, SendgridAPI.scode);
}
}
```

2nd Test:

```
@isTest
global class Mock_SendGrid_Response implements HttpCalloutMock {
// Implement this interface method
global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
    // Optionally, only send a mock response for a specific endpoint
    // and method.
   // 
System.assertEquals('https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/contactdb/recipients', req.getEndpoint());
    //System.assertEquals('POST', req.getMethod());

    // Create a fake response
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.setBody('{"Status":"Created"}');
    res.setStatusCode(201);
    return res;
}
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are running into?

Comment: You don't say what is going wrong. Some general advice is that if you are setting up a `HttpCalloutMock` then you should remove the `Test.isRunningTest()` guard and just let the mock class generate the response. Also, not urgent to fix, using static fields to setup request and response data in `SendGridAPI` is not a pattern that many people would recommend.

Comment: Somewhat related, but have you seen the [SendGrid Apex helper library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-apex)?

Comment: Thanks for the responses, at this point I think the problem I was running into was the way the api key was stored and the test wasn't able to access it so I added (SeeAllData=True) and got to 86 percent coverage. However I also got an error:"System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: {"Status":" Created"}, Actual: {"Status":"Created"}"

Comment: Furthermore, I have been learning this stuff for 3 weeks now, and have only had 2 semesters of c++ back in college, which I graduated from in 2010... Suffice it to say I am out of my league and trying to become a competent developer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear your assertion is failing due to extra whitespace in the JSON response.

Note the space before **Created**

```
testbody = '{"Status":" Created"}';
```

Should be:

```
testbody = '{"Status":"Created"}';
```

---

You can drop the `SeeAllData=true` by inserting a mock key as part of the test.

```
@TestSetup
static void setupTest() {
    insert new Key__c(api__c = 'foobar', name = 'a001I000001NO0c');
}
```

**NOTE!** That hardcoded ID in the name will cause you grief when you start moving code between environments. Try switching to some identifier that doesn't change.

---

Also, try reversing the parameter order in your assertion. The expected value should go first.

```
// ...
String expectedValue = '{"Status":"Created"}';
system.debug(expectedValue);
System.assertEquals(expectedValue, actualValue);
```